# How to compile AndroidManifest.xml without aapt

Tags: android, xml, security, android-manifest, apktool

I'm doing some low level research on Android security and wan't to create a certain AndroidManifest.xml with non-standard tags and elements. However, for building/repackaging the APK, I'm using `apktool` (which in itself uses `aapt`). Both tools sanitize the .xml during build (`apktool b ...`) file by removing entities or a custom DTD declaration for example. I also tried older versions of `apktool` (not yet older ones of `aapt`).

Is there a way to somewhat raw-compile an AndroidManifest.xml as-is from its plain text representation and therefore be able to insert non-specified tags, elements, or a DTD?

Comment: The old version of aapt ignored all sorts of stuff; like tags in the wrong spot, misspelled names, etc. You should give that a try. I'm not sure exactly what you want to add, but I just did a quick test, and was able to add several non-standard tags/attributes throughout the manifest.

Comment: Good hint, thanks. I used the oldest `aapt` I could get which is from the build-tools version 17 (see http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r17-linux.zip). The issue is that while it keeps tags, a DOCTYPE declaration pointing to a .dtd is still removed.